# django value error need more than one value to unpack

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Please before my answer is marked as duplicate, I would appreciate if someone went through it first.
I'm trying to access a products page in an ecommerce project but when I try to access the page I get a value error as below:

```
Internal Server Error: /product_view/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/shoppingmall/shop/views.py", line 15, in product_view
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, product_slug)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 85, in get_object_or_404
    return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 371, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 784, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 802, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1276, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/agozie/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1151, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
[13/Aug/2017 19:07:23] "GET /product_view/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 104231
```

I have gone through all other questions relating to mine but they all have something to do with splitting a code.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    color_id = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=(('M','Male'),('F','Female')))
    brand_id = models.ManyToManyField(Brand)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images',blank=False)
    features = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    style = models.ManyToManyField(Style)
    sub_category_id = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Category)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.00)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2, null=False)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    retailer_id = models.ForeignKey(Retailer)
    shipping_cost= models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.author = self.author.upper()
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Product, self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return('shop_product', (), {'product_slug':'self.slug'})

    def sale_price(self):
        if self.old_price > self.price:
            return self.price
        else:
            return None
```

And below is my views.py:

```
def product_view(request, product_slug):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, product_slug)
    categories = p.categories.filter(is_active=True)
    return render(request,'shop/product_view.html')
```

I am using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), `get_object_or_404` accepts `class` as a first parameter and then `*args, **kwargs` (where `class` and `kwargs` are required)

So when you call this function you need to specify `keyword arguments` to get by:

```
p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)
```

Because Django does not know by which field to get your `Product` model and that's why you receive `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.

Comment: Thanks, seems it worked, but now showing me no product matches the given query.

Comment: Can you print the `product_slug` parameter in your view and see what it looks like?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Print it how?

Comment: @Gozie in your `def product_view(request, product_slug)`, add a `print(product_slug)` on the first line and make a request to see the `product_slug` representation. (Also, a good practice is to give your URL paramters a default value of `None`, so you can do `... product_slug=None ...`)

Comment: Oh, thanks. Silly mistake, I was passing an id in the url instead of the slug

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to find a `Product` with the `product_slug` in the url, right?

`p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)` is the correct way to find an object filtered by it's field(s).

`get_object_or_404` requires that you pass any arguments other than class model to be acceptable by `get()` or `filter()` methods.